# Animated toggle button Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton

Tags: android, animation, togglebutton

im trying to make a toggle button with animation i use a toggle button and 4 XML to do so :
here is my main activity which toggle button is in it :

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_toggle_bg"
    android:checked="true"
    android:onClick="OnPressToggle" />
```

and here is my btn_toggle_bg . xml which had background values :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+android:id/background" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:id="@+android:id/toggle" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle" />
</layer-list>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my btn_toggle . xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/btn_switch_on" />
<item android:state_checked="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/btn_switch_off" />
</selector>
```

here is the new log cat

```
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979): Process: com.soheil.prolight, PID: 19979
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.soheil.prolight/com.soheil.prolight.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at com.soheil.prolight.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    ... 12 more
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979): Caused by:   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    ... 28 more
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/btn_toggle_bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020005
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.getDrawable(XResources.java:965)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:68)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.widget.ToggleButton.<init>(ToggleButton.java:51)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.widget.ToggleButton.<init>(ToggleButton.java:64)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    ... 31 more
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag LinearLayout
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
09-26 03:25:36.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drawable names cannot start with numbers:

Rename all of them to, for example:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/d1" android:duration="50"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/d2" android:duration="50"/>
...
```

Here are the naming rules you should follow:

- needs to start with a letter and not a number
- cannot contain upper case letters
- cannot contain anything other than letters and numbers

Comment: 09-26 03:10:52.926: E/AndroidRuntime(17249): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.soheil.prolight/com.soheil.prolight.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton

Comment: also under my main activity says

Comment: Failed to parse file C:\fakepath\Pro\res\drawable-hdpi\btn_toggle_bg.xml

Comment: clean your project and/or restart Eclipse

Comment: Also, is the ToggleButton xml file that you show here a part of some other xml file or is that code the whole file?

Comment: make sure the first line in your file that contains `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is **`exactly`** the first line and with no spaces before it. Also, did you clean your project/ restart Eclipse?

Comment: found it man tnx just 1 more question animation is keep playing ! i want it to play when i click on toggle button !!!?

Comment: No it's not correct, you should remove the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: you are welcome. Not sure why that is happening. The rest of your files look ok. Make sure inside you actual code you are not just toggling the button

Answer (score 0):

Move you "**btn_toggle_bg.xml**" file from "**res\drawable-hdpi**" to "**res\drawable**" folder.
It will resolve the issue